# What is the difference between php://memory and tmpfs?

Tags: php, memory

I am trying to speed up by storing some logs in-memory and then flushing them out once in a while. When looking at the options, I found that php lets you open a in-memory stream with "php://memory" or by using "dev/shm" which uses tmpfs. Is there a difference between the two? Does "php://memory" also indirectly use tmpfs?

Comment: If you only want to speed up things, take a look at memcached. I don't know why you want to dig that deep to improve performance, but imho that will not change much on that level - there are many other things to improve speed, which are documented and well used.

Comment: The rate of writes is way too high. Given the number of instances running on a machine, our disk could not handle it. Our machines still use spinning disk.